# Sudo Access with bash installer

Tags: bash, scripting

So, a while back I installed Anaconda on one of my school's computers. I did not have sudo access, yet the installer, which was just a bash script managed to change files in folders such as opt which would normally require sudo access to do. Anyone knows how that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't always need `sudo` to install packages, you can avoid it using `wget` to get the package and [`dpkg --not-root --root=$HOME`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html) to install it (assuming that there are not dependence issues).

---

Talking about python, you can use [`pip install --user`](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-to-the-user-site)  which does not need privileges.

Comment: Thanks you. Do you any list which has all the apps that can be installed via pip?